# Функции выполняються несколько раз

Tags: c#, unity3d

В обновлении почему-то код выполняется несколько раз, проверяю через Debug, при нажимании <kbd>Esc</kbd> срабатывает функция Pause, сразу Resume, а потом опять пауза. И так при других заданиях, например после выхода из диалога пауза сама появляется, хотя должно было просто закрыться окно и тому подобные проблемы. Что не так? Как убрать непонятный повтор кода?

```cpp
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class PauseMenu : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool GameIsPaused;
    public DialogWindow dialogWindow;

    public GameObject pauseMenuUI;
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            if (GameIsPaused)
            {
                Debug.Log("resume");
                Resume();
            }
            if (DialogWindow.IsDialog)
            {
                Debug.Log("dialog");
                dialogWindow.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("pause");
                Pause();
            }
        }
    }
    public void Resume()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1f;
        GameIsPaused = false;
    } 
    void Pause()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
        pauseMenuUI.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        GameIsPaused = true;
    }
    public void ToMainMenu(int sceneNumber)
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneNumber);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ты нажимаешь Esc -> выполняется первый if -> выполняется второй if -> игра паузится. return делай в ифах, чтобы дальше код не выполнялся.

Comment: Если правильно помню, лучше `GetKeyUp` обрабатывать. У вас получается несколько раз `Update` успевает отработать, пока клавиша нажата. Ну или как-то ещё нужно отслеживать, что это всё ещё тоже самое нажатие и не нужно на него несколько раз реагировать.

Comment: @CrazyElf Нет. GeyKeyDown так же как и GetKeyUp возвращает true единожды, в кадре, в котором пользователь нажал/отпустил кнопку. GetKey возвращает true, пока кнопка нажата. У него если GameIsPaused == true -> вызывается Resume, а далее, если IsDialog == false -> вызывается снова пауза.

Answer (score 0):

Здесь ошибка в условии. Исправьте на:

```
if (GameIsPaused)
        {
            Debug.Log("resume");
            Resume();
        }
        else if(dialogWindow)
        {
            Debug.Log("dialog");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("pause");
            Pause();
        }
```